# Maven build error on maven install

Tags: maven, build

I imported a maven project onto my eclipse. I clicked on Run As->Maven Install. But I got the following build error. Please help

plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:jar 2.3.2:Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:pom: 2.3.2 from/to central(http://repo1.maven.org/maven2):Error transferring file: repo1.maven.org: Unknown host repo1.maven.org

I checked /m2/repository. But could not find anything related.

Answer (score 2):

Somehow it is not able to download the required artifacts from the Maven Central repo.

A suggestion please check your network connectivity, are you behind any firewall or try to change your proxysettings.

Otherwise in the worst case try to download required artifacts manually and put them in .m2/repository (as per ur local system) and try to install again.

http://search.maven.org/#browse|672389075

It should work.

Thanks